# PHP flock() not locking

Tags: php, flock

I am having trouble figuring out why flock() is not behaving properly in the following scenario.

The following code is placed into two different PHP scripts one "test1.php" and the other "test2.php".  The point of the code is to create a file which no other process (which properly uses the flock() code) should be able to write to.  There will be many different PHP scripts which try to obtain an exclusive lock on this file, but only one should have access at any given time and all the rest should fail gracefully when they fail to get the lock.

The way I am testing this is very simple.  Both "test1.php" and "test2.php" are placed in a web accessible directory on my server.  Then from a browser such as Firefox, the first script will be executed, and then immediately after, the second script is executed from a different browser tab. This seams to work when the code is run from two different PHP scripts such as "test1.php" and "test2.php", but when the code is run twice from the same "test1.php" script or "test2.php" script the second script that is run will not immediately return with a failure.

The only reason I can think of for this, is that flock() treats all PHP processes with the same file name as the same process.  If this is the case, then when "test1.php" or "test2.php" are run twice (from two different browser tabs) PHP sees them as the same process and thus does not fail the lock.  But to me, it does not makes sense for PHP to be designed like that, thus I am hear to see if anyone else can solve this problem for me.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?
$file = 'command.bat';

echo "Starting script...";
flush();

$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
echo "Lets try locking...";
flush();

if(is_resource($handle)){
    echo "good resource...";
    flush();

    if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) === TRUE){
        echo "Got lock!";
        flush();
        sleep(100);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    }else{
        echo "Failed to get lock!";
        flush();
    }
}else{
    echo "bad resource...";
    flush();
}

exit;
```

Any help with the above is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Isn't the simpler explanation that when you are running the same php file in two tabs you're doing it too slow and the lock was already released?

Comment: Maybe not. I didn't realize in php `sleep` takes seconds rather than milliseconds. Probably rather its a browser caching issue that the page still returns the same text because it was cached client-side.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same situation and found the problem to be with the browser.

When making multiple requests to the same URL, even if doing so across tabs or windows, the browser is "smart" enough to wait until the first request completes, and then the browser attempts to run the subsequent request(s).

So, while it may look like the lock is not working, what is actually happening is that the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) is waiting for the first request to complete before running the second request.

You can verify that this is the case by opening the same URL once in Chrome and once in Firefox. By doing so, as I did, you would probably see that the lock is indeed working as expected.

Comment: I had this problem too. You can use multiple tabs in the same browser, just hard refresh the second tab (Mac: Cmd + Shift + R, or Win: Ctrl + Shift + R) and it will work.

Comment: It is not the browser waiting for subsequent attempts, but quite possibly the web server queuing them.

Answer (score 1):

flock has many restrictions, including multi-threaded servers, NFS volumes, etc.

The accepted solution is apparently to attempt to create a link instead.

Lots of discussion on this topic: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Answer (score 0):

**Your script is correct.**

What is actually happening is that fopen() is waiting until the file can be opened!

If you run the first script with sleep(20);

And the second script with sleep(1);

You will notice that the second script actually waits 20 seconds until the file is unlocked.

Therefore it will never show you "Failed to get lock" unless some critical error happens.